# Error Code : 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax missing ' '

Tags: mysql

I've coded store procedure for MySQL database. But i get this error.

```
Error Code : 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 69
```

here is my code..

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `kp`$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `getAllBulanCuti`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `getAllBulanCuti`()
BEGIN
    DECLARE jumPegawai INT;
    DECLARE counterPegawai INT;
    DECLARE bulanCuti INT;
    DECLARE currentYear INT;
    DECLARE tahunMasuk INT;
    DECLARE tahunCapeg INT;
    DECLARE bulanCutiTahunan INT;
    DECLARE bulanCutiBesar INT;
    DECLARE bulan2Winduan INT;
    DECLARE bulan3Winduan INT;
    DECLARE bulan4Winduan INT;
    DECLARE hasilMod6Capeg INT;
    DECLARE hasilMod8Masuk INT;
    DECLARE hasilMod1Capeg INT;
    DECLARE selisihCapeg INT;
    DECLARE selisihMasuk INT;

    SET jumPegawai = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pegawai);
    SET counterPegawai = 1;
    SET bulanCutiTahunan = 0;
    SET bulanCutiBesar = 0;
    SET bulan2Winduan = 0;
    SET bulan3Winduan = 0;
    SET bulan4Winduan = 0;
    SET hasilMod1Capeg = 0;
    SET hasilMod6Capeg = 0;
    SET hasilMod8Masuk = 0;
    SET selisihMasuk = 0;
    SET selisihCapeg = 0;

    WHILE counterPegawai <= jumPegawai DO
        SET currentYear = (SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CURRENT_DATE));
        SET tahunMasuk = (SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM (SELECT TGL_MASUK FROM pegawai WHERE INDEXING=counterPegawai)));
        SET tahunCapeg = (SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM (SELECT TGL_CAPEG FROM pegawai WHERE INDEXING=counterPegawai)));
        SET bulanCutiTahunan = (SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM (SELECT TGL_CAPEG FROM pegawai WHERE INDEXING=counterPegawai)));
        SET bulanCutiBesar = bulanCutiTahunan;
        SET bulan2Winduan = (SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM (SELECT TGL_MASUK FROM pegawai WHERE INDEXING=counterPegawai)));
        SET bulan3Winduan = bulan2Winduan;
        SET bulan4Winduan = bulan2Winduan;
        SET selisihMasuk = currentYear-tahunMasuk;
        SET selisihCapeg = currentYear-tahunCapeg;
        SET hasilMod1Capeg = (SELECT MOD(selisihCapeg,1));
        SET hasilMod6Capeg = (SELECT MOD(selisihCapeg,6));
        SET hasilMod8Masuk = (SELECT MOD(selisihMasuk,8));

        IF hasilMod1Capeg=0 AND hasilMod8Masuk=0 THEN
            UPDATE pegawai SET BULAN_CUTI_TAHUN=bulanCutiTahunan,BULAN_CUTI_BESAR=0 WHERE INDEXING=counterPegawai;
            IF selisihMasuk/8 = 2 THEN
                UPDATE pegawai SET BULAN_2_WINDUAN=bulan2Winduan,BULAN_3_WINDUAN=0,BULAN_4_WINDUAN=0 WHERE INDEXING=counterPegawai;
            ELSEIF selisihMasuk/8 = 3 THEN
                UPDATE pegawai SET BULAN_3_WINDUAN=bulan3Winduan,BULAN_2_WINDUAN=0,BULAN_4_WINDUAN=0 WHERE INDEXING=counterPegawai;
            ELSE
                UPDATE pegawai SET BULAN_4_WINDUAN=bulan4Winduan,BULAN_2_WINDUAN=0,BULAN_3_WINDUAN=0 WHERE INDEXING=counterPegawai;
            END IF;
        ELSEIF hasilMod6Capeg=0 AND hasilMod8Masuk=0 THEN
            UPDATE pegawai SET BULAN_CUTI_BESAR=bulanCutiBesar,BULAN_CUTI_TAHUN=0 WHERE INDEXING=counterPegawai;
            IF selisihMasuk/8 = 2 THEN
                UPDATE pegawai SET BULAN_2_WINDUAN=bulan2Winduan,BULAN_3_WINDUAN=0,BULAN_4_WINDUAN=0 WHERE INDEXING=counterPegawai;
            ELSEIF selisihMasuk/8 = 3 THEN
                UPDATE pegawai SET BULAN_3_WINDUAN=bulan3Winduan,BULAN_2_WINDUAN=0,BULAN_4_WINDUAN=0 WHERE INDEXING=counterPegawai;
            ELSE
                UPDATE pegawai SET BULAN_4_WINDUAN=bulan4Winduan,BULAN_2_WINDUAN=0,BULAN_3_WINDUAN=0 WHERE INDEXING=counterPegawai;
            END IF;
        ELSE
            UPDATE pegawai SET BULAN_CUTI_TAHUN=bulanCutiTahun,BULAN_CUTI_BESAR=0,BULAN_2_WINDUAN=0,BULAN_3_WINDUAN=0,BULAN_4_WINDUAN=0 WHERE INDEXING=counterPegawai;
        END IF;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

your solution will be apreciated :)

Comment: Please indicate which is line 69.

Comment: ELSE
UPDATE pegawai SET BULAN_4_WINDUAN=bulan4Winduan,BULAN_2_WINDUAN=0,BULAN_3_WINDUAN=0 WHERE INDEXING=counterPegawai;

in else if..

Comment: Are you sure the code you posted matches what is in the database being compiled?

Comment: i'm sure.. i've compiled that code many times.. But i always get that error..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing

```
END WHILE;
```

This is required to terminate you DO WHILE loop.

Comment: Perfect ... did you used a microscope? :)

Comment: No, I saw the inconsistent indentation at the end.  At least the code was well indented, making it easy to spot this one.